# Syncronization with angularjs $http function

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous, promise

I am new to angularjs and I have a very small app that loads contacts from my server. The code snippet here is the complete app.js. 
The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the server call with sync. In the code snippet, when I refresh the page, alert 3 is displayed, then alert 2, and then finally alert 4. The function is immediately returning since the server http call take some time to do. So what I get in the browser is a display of the 2 test item in the array "contacts". Alert 4 finally comes along, but it is too late. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.service('ContactService', function ($http) {

    //contacts array to hold list of all contacts - 2 entries for test

    //var $contacts = [];
    var contacts = [
        {
        id: 0,
        'First_Name': 'Harmon',
        'Last_Name': 'Adams',
        'Home_Phone': '123-2343-44'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            'First_Name': 'Sam',
            'Last_Name': 'Spade',
            'Home_Phone': '123-2343-44'
        }
    ];

    // returns the contacts list
    this.list = function () {
    //    var contacts = [];
        $http.post('http://localhost/Contacts7/GetData.php', {'cat' : 'Friends'}).
            success(function(data)  {
                contacts =  data.datarecords;
                alert('4 - within $post - '+contacts);
            }).
            error(function(data, status){
                alert('error!');
            });
        alert('3 - before return - '+contacts);
        return contacts;
    }
});

module.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService ) {
    $scope.contacts = ContactService.list();
    alert('2 - after list - '+ $scope.contacts);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Contact Dialer </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController">

    <div class="container" >
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row col-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary btn-l btn-block" ng-click="GetByCat('Favorites')">Favorites</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row col-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary btn-l btn-block" ng-click="GetByCat('Friends')">Friends</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row col-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary btn-l btn-block" ng-click="GetByCat('Loose Friends')">Loose Friends</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row col-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary btn-l btn-block" ng-click="GetByCat('Loose_Loose Friends')">Loose-Loose Friends</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row col-centered">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-Primary btn-l btn-block" ng-click="GetByCat('Business')">Business</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 button-row">
        </div>
    </div>
        {{xxx}}
        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
            <th class = 'text-center'>Name</th>
            <th class = 'text-center'>Home Phone</th>
            <th class = 'text-center'>Mobile Phone</th>
            <th class = 'text-center'>Bus. Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat='contact in contacts'>
                <th class = 'text-center' >{{contact.Last_Name}}, {{contact.First_Name}}</th>
                <td class = 'text-center'>{{contact.Home_Phone}}</td>
                <td class = 'text-center'>{{contact.Mobile_Phone}}</td>
                <td class = 'text-center'>{{contact.Business_Phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table></div>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</h
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't return `contacts` from your service because contacts is going to be determined asynchronously. Instead you need to return a *promise* for the contacts, which you can use to populate your controller's contacts when they are done being retrieved.

Service:

```
module.service('ContactService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        list: function () {
            return $http.post('http://localhost/Contacts7/GetData.php', 
                              {'cat' : 'Friends'})
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data.datarecords;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw new Error("Failed to retrieve contacts!");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Note** You may have noticed that I changed the first line from using the magic dependency injection style to using the array-style dependency injection. This is just my personal preference (because I consider the magic DI style to be a bad idea), and not something that you have to do. The same applies to the code below.

Controller:

```
module.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', 'ContactService',
                                        function ($scope, ContactService ) {
    $scope.contacts = [];
    ContactService.list()
    .then(function (contacts) {
        $scope.contacts = contacts;
        alert('2 - after list - '+ $scope.contacts);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: This answer is good but why did you change his DI syntax to array syntax?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Because using the magic DI syntax is an [antipractice](http://daemon.co.za/2014/03/complexity-creeps-concerned-for-future-of-angular/).

Comment: Yeah, but in my humble opinion it is best not to make subjective changes to OP's code - having advised to several Angular workshops in the past I'd say they are divided roughly equally between people using the array syntax and people using ng-min (now [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)). I would definitely not call it "abuse of the language" or an antipattern per se - after all minifiers are tooling themselves and are not 'above frameworks' - when the minifiers make assumptions about source code that are not viable here the minifiers are at fault.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I very much respect your opinion, but in my opinion, I think the code I post in my own answers should be up to the standards of what I consider quality code, and I consider magic DI to be very perilous code. The fact that the magic DI breaks minification is just a symptom of the fact that the way magic DI is accomplished is a (very clever, but still) really bad idea. Minification libraries operate within the boundaries of the way the syntax is defined while magic DI functions by exploting a hacky loophole. _That_ is what I would call making assumptions about source code.

Comment: As I said, the minification issue is just a symptom. Who knows what other critical flaws we'll find in magic DI down the road. After all, all it takes is a `Function.prototype.toString = function () { "Goodbye!" };` to bring the whole thing tumbling down. As pointed out in the article I linked to, the maintainers of ng-annotate have found a very complicated solution to a very uncomplicated problem. If that doesn't scream "bad idea", I don't know what does.

Comment: Fair enough, you're well within your right to promote whatever practices you'd like in your answers - but `Function#toString` is part of the language specification (15.3.4.2) and changing `Function.prototype.toString` is as bad as changing `Function.prototype.apply` which basically breaks everything in modern JS engines. Most other languages I know let you get parameter names too: C#, Java (8), Python, Ruby and really most modern high level languages. I guess I just disagree it's a loophole: minifiers are the ones jumping through hoops but again - you're entitled to your favorite practices :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If JavaScript provided a clean mechanism for getting parameter names (and it's almost surprising that it doesn't), then I would be on board with magic DI. The `.toString()` approach just seems way too hacky to me (though you may well be right that my concerns here are unfounded). C#'s `nameof()` is still in beta. JS may well get something similar before long, and if that happens and magic DI is updated to use that, it will get my un-coveted seal of approval and it will be the minifiers' turn to get in line with what's considered acceptable use.

Comment: As a closing note, I would say that minifiers are jumping through hoops to mitigate a genuine problem (network latency), while the ng-minners' work is directed at a non-issue (the desire to use a nifty feature that provides almost zero benefit). I have all the respect in the world for both groups, and I'm sure that most of them are a lot smarter than me, but I feel that one of those two camps is jumping through hoops for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return contacts object from outside ajax.
It should be return contacts object from its success callback.

```
// returns the contacts list
this.list = function () {
//    var contacts = [];
$http.post('http://localhost/Contacts7/GetData.php', {'cat' : 'Friends'}).then(
//success call back
function(data)  {
    contacts =  data.datarecords;
    alert('4 - within $post - '+contacts);
    return contacts;
},
//error call back
function(data, status){
    //error handling can be done here
    alert('error!');
    return;
});
```

Hope this may help full to you.